# Simple command line HTTP server

Tags: command-line, webserver, http, html

I have a script which generates a daily report which I want to serve to the so called general public. The problem is I don't want to add to my headaches maintance of a HTTP server (e.g. Apache) with all the configurations and security implications.

Is there a dead simple solution for serving one small HTML page without the effort of configuring a full blown HTTP server?

Comment: See answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4994745 in question [One line ftp server in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4994638) on [SO].

Comment: Why not just use netcat?

Comment: Indeed! Use FTP, like the World Wide Web did before HTTP was finished! (Although I suppose it wasn't quite as world-wide in early 1990s. )

Comment: A large collection of methods have been compiled in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-accepting-get-post-requests

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, nweb.

Can be found here: [nweb.c](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sumpygump/9908417/raw/5fa991fda103d0b7a0c38512394a83ccada9ad6c/nweb23.c)

(previously at [ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/systems/library/es-nweb/index.html))

To compile nweb.c:

```
gcc -O -DLINUX nweb.c -o nweb
```

Comment: It works well, but 2 comments for users: 1) it serves `index.html` from the provided directory, 2) from `nweb --help`: "Not Supported: URLs including "..", Java, Javascript, CGI". So, for example, [Live.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346716/how-do-i-make-firefox-auto-refresh-on-file-change) to automatically refresh the page on file update does not work.

Comment: That's right, but you actually just need to add the wanted extensions to the list of mime types for the files to be served. Same for index.html, you can adjust that very easely.

Answer (score 296):

Try [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html):

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

Or, for Python 2

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

To bind an IP Address, do

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080 -b 0.0.0.0
```

or for Python 3

```
python3 -m http.server 8080 -b 0.0.0.0
```

It will serve whatever's in the [CWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_working_directory) (e.g. index.html) at http://0.0.0.0:8000.

Comment: You can optionally specify a port number like this: `python3 -m http.server 1337`. You can't specify which IP to bind to as far as I can tell. Note: To listen to port 80 you must have root privileges, e.g.: `sudo python3 -m http.server 80`

Comment: This one is nice but it has an issue with redirecting to an URL with a trailing slash added. That's why I prefer the twistd version: `twistd -n web -p 8000 --path . `

Comment: To change default listening port 8080  (with python2) to something else, just put a port number after: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000`

Answer (score 83):

There is a [Big list of http static server one-liners](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255):

> To get on this list, a solution must:
>
> 1. serve static files using your current directory (or a specified directory) as the server root
> 2. be able to be run with a single, one line command (dependencies are fine if they're a one-time thing)
> 3. serve basic file types (html, css, js, images) with proper mime types,
>      require no configuration (from files or otherwise) beyond the command itself (no framework-specific servers, etc)
> 4. must run, or have a mode where it can run, in the foreground (i.e. no daemons)

For example:

- [Twisted (Python)](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255#twisted-python)

  ```
  twistd -n web -p 8000 --path .
  ```
- [Erlang](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255#erlang):

  ```
  erl -s inets -eval 'inets:start(httpd,[{server_name,"NAME"},{document_root, "."},{server_root, "."},{port, 8000},{mime_types,[{"html","text/html"},{"htm","text/html"},{"js","text/javascript"},{"css","text/css"},{"gif","image/gif"},{"jpg","image/jpeg"},{"jpeg","image/jpeg"},{"png","image/png"}]}]).'
  ```
- [Plack (Perl)](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255#plack-perl)

  ```
  cpan Plack
  plackup -MPlack::App::Directory -e 'Plack::App::Directory->new(root=>".");' -p 8000
  ```
- [webfs](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255#webfs)

  ```
  webfsd -F -p 8000
  ```
- [Ruby 1.9.2+](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255#ruby-192)

  ```
  ruby -run -ehttpd . -p8000
  ```

Answer (score 62):

Use `node.js` , fast and lightweight.

Or

just use simple `nc` netcat command to start a quick webserver on a port and serve the content of a file including the server response headers.

Reference from Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Setting_up_a_one-shot_webserver_on_port_8080_to_present_the_content_of_a_file

```
{ echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"; cat some.file; } | nc -l -p 8080
{ echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: $(wc -c <some.file)\r\n\r\n"; cat some.file; } | nc -l -p 8080
```

Comment: A bare node.js process with only the interactive shell running takes 15MB (7.5 is shared) of RAM. And then you have to run the HTTP server inside it. It is funny that people see it as lightweight. ;-)

Comment: yeah I consider it light weight, you can scale well with such less memory footprint. Please read http://thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/5/6/serving-static-files-from-node-js  However, if you find it cumbersome to use node.js, then the simple netcat utility serves the short lived purpose well.

Comment: You are of course right if you compare node with Apache but what I found amusing was how node looks when compared to http://cr.yp.to/publicfile.html or something similar. :)

Comment: hmmmmm.. ok ;-)

Comment: +1 for the `nc` based solution :). Note that the `-ne` flags for `echo` may not be portable, using the [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) command instead may be a better alternative.

Comment: Chrome won't stop throbbing unless you use the second nc command. Also, not both of the nc commands show will quit after responding. You can keep restarting it with: `while :; do { echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: $(wc -c <some.file)\r\n\r\n"; cat some.file; } | nc -l -p 8080; done`. Use ctrl+z to but it to sleep.

Comment: @RayFoss what does throbbing mean? Is the purpose of the second nc command that adds `Content-Length: $(wc -c <some.file)` to the first nc command to stop Chrome from throbbing?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555544/how-does-this-nc-command-work-as-a-http-server

Comment: You can also add the `-N` flag to `nc` and both nc commands will work. It will make nc close the socket after sending the file and this is what the browser is waiting for.

Answer (score 46):

Since version 5.4.0 PHP also has a [built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

You can Specify the web server's documents directory with `-t`, for example:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t /var/lib/www
```

If you want to be able to access the server over the network then:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t /var/lib/www
```

Comment: Wow that was easy and helpful!

Comment: This one is really nice if you want to test php-scripts locally.

Answer (score 23):

Node has a simple, fast, light HTTP server module. To install:

```
sudo npm install http-server -g
```

(Assuming you have `node` and `npm` already installed.)

To run it, using the current directory as the website root:

```
http-server
```

This creates a server on `http://0.0.0.0:8080/`.

Comment: It works. I have a Node project on a FreeBSD machine, I just run `npm install -D http-server` inside project directory and then add the following lines to my `package.json` file: `"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack && cd src/public && http-server"
  },` now I just need to run `npm run build` on project directory to start the HTTP server, listening on port 8080 by default.

Comment: First I tried "`python3 -m http.server`", but it's single-threaded and only 1 client can download at a time, the others need to wait. This solution with Node.js works better, due to the async nature of Node. If you want to share a file with several people, use this.

Comment: The module may be "light", node.js isn't. You'd be running a JS runtime just to serve static files.

Comment: To add CORS support: `http-server -p 3000 --cors`

Answer (score 8):

A simple fix/enhancement to a slightly unfairly (imho) down voted answer might also work. Let's set up the html file first ...

```
echo '<html><head><title>My Test File</title></head><body><h1>OK!</h1></body></html>' > my_file.html
```

(Thx to Steve Folly for catching my typo in the HTML above. fixed.)

Now you can serve it up with this one-liner:

```
while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n" | cat - my_file.html  | nc -l -p 8080; done
```

This basic idea lends itself to other tricks that might work for you via other `cat` or subshell ideas such as:

```
while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\nI think the date is $(date), Have a good day!" | nc -l -p 8080; done
```

Comment: And you could also pass `Content-Length` as shown in my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725430/http-test-server-accepting-get-post-requests/52351480#52351480

Answer (score 6):

Simple Ruby one liner to serve a directory:

```
ruby -run -e httpd . -p 8080
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `SimpleHTTPServer` in Python.

```
mkdir ~/public_html
command_to_generate_output > ~/public_html/output.txt

(cd ~/public_html; python -c 'import SimpleHTTPServer,BaseHTTPServer; BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", 8080), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler).serve_forever()')
```

The first two lines are setup for the web server.  The last line creates a simple web server, opened on port 8080, which only serves files from `~/public_html`.  If only one file is in that directory, then only that is exposed: `http://localhost:8080/output.txt`.

Comment: that's what i use, just copy the lastline and paste it on a `.py` file, then run it with `python` (or make it executable). Keep in mind that you have to run with python 2.x interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

try caddy

`curl https://getcaddy.com | bash`

serve content from /var/www 
`caddy -root /var/www "browse"`

now you find the server at http://localhost:2015

- https://caddyserver.com/
- https://nwgat.ninja/quick-easy-caddy-a-http-2-web-server-with-a-twist/

Comment: I love to just `caddy` from a local directory and enjoy having a modern and secure webserver.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to install lighttpd. Following are suggested steps to install lighttpd on a Unbuntu 12.04 LTS.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade --show-upgraded
apt-get install lighttpd
ifconfig
http://[your-ip-address]:80
/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (Edit to add server.port)
server.port = "8080"
```

Note: Documentroot is where all web accessible files will be places. The location is /var/wwww

The above step will install a basic lighttpd web server. For more information refer the following references

**References:**

- [lighttpd Web Server on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise)](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/lighttpd/lighttpd-web-server-on-ubuntu-12-04-preci)
- [Lighttpd Description](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/lighttpd?highlight=%28%28lighttpd%29%29)
- [Lighttpd starts but doesn't work. lighttpd.pid Permission Denied](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344600/lighttpd-starts-but-doesnt-work-lighttpd-pid-permission-denied)
- [Getting Started - Linode](https://www.linode.com/docs/getting-started/)
- [Web Server for testing on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113117/web-server-for-testing-on-linux)
- [Tech Tip: Really Simple HTTP Server with Python](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python)
- [Which Light Weight, Open Source Web Server is Right for You?](https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/807641-which-light-weight-open-source-web-server-is-right-for-you)
- [6 Excellent Linux/Open Source Web Servers](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/reviews/7239/1)
- [Lighttpd configuration](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/TutorialConfiguration)

Answer (score 3):

`./devd -o -a -P devd:devd .`

- -o opens url in browser
- -a for all interfaces
- -P auth user/pass
- . serve files in same directory

https://github.com/cortesi/devd/releases

Answer (score 3):

I've improved the `nc` solution a bit so it:

- Adds the `filename=` hint,
- Runs in a loop until <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>,
- Saves a PID to `/tmp/serveFile-$PORT` so you can kill it later easily.

.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1;
if [ "$FILE" == "" ] ; then echo "Usage: $0 <file-to-serve> [<port:7979>]"; exit; fi
PORT=${2:-7979}
echo Serving $FILE at $PORT, PID: $$
echo $$ > /tmp/serveFilePID-$PORT

while true; do 
    { echo -ne "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: $(wc -c <$FILE)\r\nContent-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$(basename $FILE)\"\r\n\r\n"; cat $FILE; } | nc -l $PORT
    CODE=$?
    #echo "Code: $CODE";
    if [ $CODE -gt 128 ] ; then break; fi;
done;

rm /tmp/serveFilePID-$PORT
```

One could also use `nc -k -l ...` but this way you can

- do custom actions between files served,
- make several files alternate.

Answer (score 2):

Simple netcat example to put in bash script:

```
while true ; do nc -l 80 <index.html ; done
```

Comment: That entirely fails to speak HTTP.

Comment: I tried `while [ 1=1 ] ; do echo "TEST" |  nc -l 80; done` - going to http://127.0.0.1 indeed returns the contents. I had to do that as root though. So in an extremely crude way - it can get the job done, and I like that. I tried going to http://my-hostnname.local on another machine in the LAN and it worked too.

Answer (score 2):

Oldschool Ruby [*WEBrick*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html) HTTP server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'webrick'
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8000,
                                 :DocumentRoot => '~/webrickroot')

# stop server with Ctrl-C
trap('INT') { server.stop }
server.start
```

Make sure to modify the `DocumentRoot` for your setup. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397792/webrick-mount-proc).

Answer (score 2):

You can piggy back on [xinetd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinetd).  Put the following config file into /etc/xinetd.d/ and **service xinetd reload**:

```
service http
{
  flags = REUSE IPv4
  protocol = tcp
  socket_type = stream
  port = 80
  wait = no
  user = nobody
  server = /bin/echo
  server_args = -e HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently\nContent-Length: 0\nLocation: https://goo.gl/\n\n
  disable = no
}
```

Works for my redirecting purposes:

```
# wget 127.0.0.1
--2016-04-04 22:56:20--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://goo.gl/ [following]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I used these instructions to install a web server on my CentOS machine without having to use sudo or touch any system files:

First install node (see the [latest available version of the nodejs package here](https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/) and change the package filename in the wget):

```
$ cd ~
$ wget https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/node-v18.10.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ tar node-v18.10.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

then install http-server:

```
$ export PATH=~/node-v18.10.0-linux-x64/bin:$PATH
$ npm install http-server
```

then run http-server on port 12321:

```
$ ~/node-v18.10.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server -p 12321
```

Comment: For future readers coming here from search: this is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. There are many easier and smaller solutions (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994638/one-line-ftp-server-in-python/4994745#4994745 suggested in question comments).

Answer (score 1):

SFK worth mentioning here

http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html

an excellent multipurpose tool with no dependencies

available in both deb and rpm flavours

`sfk httpserv -port 1234`

will serve current directory

`sfk httpserv -port 1234 -rw`

will also allow file uploading

Answer (score 1):

My five cents, written in shell: https://gitlab.com/mezantrop/supermatic

> Supermatic can run on FreeBSD and any other OS which has Bourne Shell
>   and inetd-like daemon. It serves static HTML and TXT files along with
>   GIF, JPEG and PNG image formats. What's about any other standards and
>   features? No, never heard of them.

Answer (score 1):

A docker based one liner so you don't have to have any particular language installed:

```
docker run --rm -i -p 8000:8000 -v $(pwd):/app -w /app ruby:alpine ruby -run -ehttpd . -p8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash: [A web server in a shell script](https://debian-administration.org/article/371/A_web_server_in_a_shell_script).

Also, you'll need xinetd (I believe available in any distro) to listen port and run the script when needed, so you don't have to code tcp stack etc in bash.

Answer (score 0):

To nweb.c I have added directory listing functionality. https://github.com/jbabuc/nweb

nweb.c, simple http server with directory listing.
nwebs, statically compiled binary for linux.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that `nweb` was already mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32184/377345). Please review your answer and check if you can add anything new to make it more distinct. Alternatively, consider submitting an edit proposal to the accepted answer.