# How to wrap iptables commands around Ruby webrick server going up and down in a single command/script?

Tags: iptables, webserver, ruby

I would like to use this Ruby *WEBrick* server [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159336/44370) for on-demand showcasing of some random web pages. So I set up some forwarding exception on my adsl modem local web interface(192.168.2.1). Then enabled [`iptables`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) with a very basic [setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Simple_stateful_firewall). I use an `iptables` command to temporarily open port 3000 for tcp, then launch the *Ruby* script, and when I interrupt the server(with ctlr-c), it closes and I remove that very same filter rule to tidy things up(even though I know the rule wouldn't persist accross reboots):

```
# sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
# ./myscript(ruby) - server goes up
<ctrl-c>          - server goes down
# sudo iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

How would I do that with a single command/script? I can make an *alias* to wrap the first command and starting the server, but it's not clear how to take care of the exit and the last command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with the shell. But since the script is already trapping the interrupt signal, you might as well leverage that and add an extra command there as you can execute commands with that interpreter, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'webrick'
system *%W(sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT)
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3000,
                                 :DocumentRoot => '~/webrickroot')

# stop server with Ctrl-C
trap('INT') { server.stop; system *%W(sudo iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT) }
server.start
```

Using for convenience an *array of blank separated words* with [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) to echo some [concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970819) for the sanity of how the commands' constructs could be interpreted and processed generally. Every token is seemingly supplied to `sudo` as an argument here<sup>1</sup>. You will of course be asked for your password(twice) as `iptables` requires superuser privileges for any significant use, including interactively adding and removing rules.

---

<sub>1. As [demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650636/forming-sanitary-shell-commands-or-system-calls-in-ruby/4651702#comment5126013_4651702) with the apt `ruby -e 'system *%W(ls -l foo; rm -rf /)'`. Of course DO NOT try this without the splat+word array component(*%W) while quoting what is inside the parentheses.</sub>