# Simple http server from the command line that will always cause a timeout

Tags: command-line, webserver, http, timeout

Regarding the question [Simple command line HTTP server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32182/simple-command-line-http-server) I would like to know, what is the simplest method for creating a http server listening on a specified port that will always cause timeout (it just eats the request and never responds).

I am looking for a dead simple oneliner. It would be useful for the purpose of testing clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NetCat` to just listen on a port and do nothing:

```
nc -l $PORT
```

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't have to respond, you can use `netcat`.

```
nc -lp [port] -w [timeout]
```

Option `-l` to use netcat as server, `-p` for the port and
`-w` for the timeout.

Comment: -w [timeout] closes the socket, producing a broken pipe exception in the client (e.g. Excon::Errors::SocketError: Broken pipe - Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)). It was not exacly my usecase, but it can help someone.